# Logic for pairing up two sets of values in ArrayList with duplication

Tags: java, arraylist, logic

I'm baffled on the logic of programming this. I'm sure it's extremely simple.

So, I have an `ArrayList<String>` with values `A, B, C, D, E, F, G`. Indexed in that order.

I would like to randomly select a unique letter for each but have no duplication.

The output would look similar to this.

```
A:B
B:A
C:E
D:F
E:C
F:D
```

I’ve tried shuffling the ArrayList then moving the index by two, but couldn’t think of a way to prevent duplication, and also randomly selecting indexes then pairing them up but this only works with even numbers.

Comment: can you please provide the complete problem statement or elaborate it?

Comment: I've simplified the problem quite a bit. I just cannot think of the logic for doing this. I'm creating an android app which needs to pair up two users in a limited group of users.

Comment: You said _"...but have duplication"_ (twice),  but did you really mean _"...but **not have** duplication"_?

Comment: so you want to create random pairs of letters, without duplicating those pairs?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes, sorry. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Yeah

Answer (score 1):

This should be all you need:

```
ArrayList<String> list = // your list containing the values

ArrayList<String> shuffled = new ArrayList<>(list);
Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
```

This will give you a second `ArrayList<String>` that  contains all the values of `list` in random order without duplicates.

Comment: If [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) itself is off-limits for you, just implement the algorithm for yourself, as conveniently described in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution
{
    public static class Pair
    {
        public String a;
        public String b;

        public Pair(String a,String b)
        {
            this.a=a;
            this.b=b;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o)
        {
            if((this.a.equals(o.a))&&(this.b.equals(o.b)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if((this.b.equals(o.a))&&(this.a.equals(o.b)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return a+":"+b;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        ......
        .....
        ......
        //list now contains {A,B,C,D,E,F,G}
        Set<Pair> letterset=new HashSet<Pair>();
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
            {
                Pair pair=new Pair(list.get(i),list.get(j));
                letterset.add(pair);
            }
        }
        Iterator<Pair> iter=letterset.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(iter.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Here
 1. **Pair:** it is a class which holds two letters a and b, if two objects same set they are considered to be equal as implemented in the equals() function
 2. **letterset:** set has been creates to remove the  duplicate objects.
 3. **nested loop created to create pairs**

I hope this is what you wanted.